# Kentico breakcrumb webpart not using the page alias

Tags: kentico

I have two pages sitting in a folder named "Auxiliary Nav". The pages have aliases set so 'Auxuliary-Nav' doesn't show in their URLs. I thought all was good until I looked at my breadcrumbs. Ideally, the breadcrumb shouldn't show "Auxiliary Nav".

I'm using the Breadcrumbs web part on a master page, but can't see a setting for this. I had also thought about just using the CSS list menu, but not sure if this would help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off "Show in navigation" for "Auxiliary Nav".

[image: Navigation options]

Comment: There is a setting that is amiss on one page. The breadcrumb on the other page is doing what i expect. Time to start digging.

Thanks!